# How to use profile in Spring-boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to use profile in Spring-boot application. I don't know how to do it.

How to modify the following code ?

```
package com.example.demo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class EnglishGreeting implements HelloWorldService {

    @Override
    public String greeting() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "hello world";
    }

}

package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SpanichGreeting implements HelloWorldService {

    @Override
    public String greeting() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "hola monda";
    }

}
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything with profiles in the code, so we don't understand the problem either.

Comment: What is actually going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to select either one implementation depending on the profile, you need to add the annotations.

```
@Component
@Profile("en")
public class EnglishGreeting implements HelloWorldService

@Component
@Profile("es")
public class SpanichGreeting implements HelloWorldService {
```

Running the program with `-Pes` would enable the `es` profile, and it would use the spanish implementation when autowiring.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding `@Profile("en")` and `@Profile("es")` you must create property files called application-en.properties and application-es.properties.

You can create a property in each file for example:

`application-en.properties`

```
greeting.text=hello world
```

`application-es.properties`

```
greeting.text=hola monda
```

And in your service add a variable that takes that value in.

Like this:

```
@Component
public class SpanishGreeting implements HelloWorldService {

@Value("${greeting.text})"
String greeting

      @Override
      public String greeting() {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return this.greeting;
      }
}
```

More info about `@Value` here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation